# req.body is empty in express when sending JSON string in http request

Tags: json, angular, express

Express is receiving an empty json string {} and I have not been able to figure out why. I have tried both bodyParser and express.json for the json parser and have gotten the same result. I am unable to find anything wrong with my headers either.  Below is the relevant code:

**HTTP  Client Sedning the Request**

```
    private sendRequest<T>(verb: string, url: string, body?: any)
    : Observable<T> {

    let myHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
   // myHeaders = myHeaders.set("Access-Key", "<secret>");
    // myHeaders = myHeaders.set("Application-Names", ["Rapid Recipes", "MSsanto"]);
    

    
    return this.http.request<T>(verb, url, {
      body: JSON.stringify(body), headers: myHeaders })
      .pipe(catchError((error: Response) => throwError(`Network Error: ${error.statusText} (${error.status})`)));

  }
```

**Express App**

```
   var app = express();
//app.use(bodyParser());
//app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: 'Smb' }));
//app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json());

 app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:4200');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET','POST','OPTIONS','PUT','PATCH','DELETE',);
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Authorization', 'X-Requested-With, Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'application/json');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
  next();

 
app.post("/:type", function (req, res) {
  console.log('The POST was received');
  
  var typeName = req.originalUrl.substring(1).toLowerCase();
  var params = {};
  params[typeName] = 1;
  params["_id"] = 1


 console.log("the request bod is " + JSON.stringify(req.body)); //this returns {}
  

  var dbm = dbModel.findOne({}, params);

 
  dbm.updateOne({ $push: { "recipe": req.body } }, function (err, data)

  {

    if (err) {
      res.send(err);

    }

    else {
      res.send(data)
      console.log('data saved!');

    } } ) }
  )
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not sending a content type in request headers.

```
myHeaders = myHeaders.set("Content-Type", "application/json");
```

Comment: I tired that but it returns internal server error 500 when I set it to application/json

Comment: What's the text of the 500 error?  That should point you to the actual error.

Comment: I was able to capture the error.  It wasn't' a 500 actually.  It has something to do with CORS.  "Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:3000/Recipe' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.
zone-evergreen.js:2845 POST http://localhost:3000/Recipe net::ERR_FAILED

Comment: I was able to resolve the issue by setting the header as you suggested and also adding the following lines to the express app:                    

var cors = require('cors');

app.use(cors());